# Loop until no exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, exception, webrequest

I want to go once through a loop but only if an exception is thrown go back through the loop. How would I write this in vb.net? I am trying to make a web request using a proxy server. Here is the code I have so far that currently does not work.

```
Public Sub checkproxy()

    Dim myWebRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com")
    Dim myProxy As New WebProxy() 
    Dim proxyAddress = "http://www.example.com:8080"
    Dim newUri As New Uri(proxyAddress)
    myProxy.Address = newUri
    myWebRequest.Proxy = myProxy
    Dim switch As String = "b"
    Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse
    Do Until switch = "a"
        Try
            myWebRequest.GetResponse()
            switch = "a"
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        End Try
    Loop
    RichTextBox1.Text = myWebResponse.Headers.ToString
    myWebResponse.Close()
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected"
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I was unaware thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`Exit Do` is what you're looking for:

```
Do Until switch = "a"
    Try
        myWebRequest.GetResponse()
        switch = "a"
        Exit Do
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Try
Loop
```

Comment: The program still seems to hang for some reason. Would it be something to do with the web request part? I have the proxy server stopped when I call checkproxy() then I wait 10 seconds and start proxyserver up however the program continues to hang.

Comment: debugger is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Actually all you need to do is to change your `Do Until ... Loop` to a `Do ... Loop Until`, which will always run the loop once and then check the loop condition before executing the loop again:

```
Do 
    Try
        myWebRequest.GetResponse()
        switch = "a"
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Try
Loop Until switch = "a"
```

See the [Do Loop page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) for the syntax and further explanation

Answer (score 0):

I needed `Exit Do` as stated in MarcinJuraszek answer I also needed to create webrequest in try function instead of at the start of the code. Here is an update on working code.

```
Public Sub checkproxy()

    Dim myWebRequest As WebRequest
    Dim myProxy As New WebProxy() 
    Dim proxyAddress = "http://www.example.com:8080"
    Dim newUri As New Uri(proxyAddress)
    myProxy.Address = newUri
    Dim switch As String = "b"
    Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse
    Do Until switch = "a"
        Try
            myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com")
            myWebRequest.Proxy = myProxy
            myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse()
            switch = "a"
            Exit Do
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        End Try
    Loop
    RichTextBox1.Text = myWebResponse.Headers.ToString
    myWebResponse.Close()
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch is not required.

```
Do While True
    Try
        myWebRequest.GetResponse()
        Exit Do
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End Try
Loop
```

In addition, it may be wise to allow the user to exit the loop after a set time to avoid an infinite loop.